# Reading tab and comma delimited table with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Is there a way to read table delimited with tab and comma with Pandas?

For example, this is one row of my table:

```
They have been divested of many of their basis rights , and their voices can not be heard by anyone .   14  73  can,can,MD,VP,S,S,can,can,MD,their,they,punct,They,they,PRP,and-their-voices-can-not-be-heard,and-they-voice-can-not-be-hear,CC-punct-NNS-MD-RB-VB-VBN,They,they,PRP,MD^VP^S^S^ROOT,MD_VP-VP_S-S_S-S_ROOT,MD_VP_S-VP_S_S-S_S_ROOT,MD^VP_MD-MD^VP^S_NP_punct-MD^VP^S_NP_punct-MD^VP^S^S_S_VP_VP_NP_PP_NP_PP_NP_punct-MD^VP^S^S_S_VP_VP_NP_PP_NP_PP_IN,can-their-their-their-of-,can-they-they-they-of-,MD-punct-punct-punct-IN-,MD^VP_VP_VB-MD^VP_VP_VP_VBN-MD^VP_VP_VP_PP_IN-MD^VP_VP_VP_PP_NP_NN,be-heard-by-anyone-,hear,VB-VBN-IN-NN-,3,pl,pres,y,n,n,n,hear,DYNAMIC,common,common,04981941-N,04981139-N,04983122-N,04916342-N,00001740-N,cond,none,false,false,true,false,2.934518319775894E-4,6.497861993793049E-4,0.0,0.013247254129300463,0.0023476146558204705,47708.0,0.019598390207091837,0.002871635784352528,0.03081244235768916,0.27477571895691705,0.18946507923198114,0.1237947514043701,0.07179089460885409,0.009641988764988813,0.0026201056426603878,adv.all,NONE,noun.attribute,VBN,none,cond,passive,02169702-V,NONE,NONE,NONE,02106506-V,dy
```

Thank you!

Comment: what do you want as your expected output? a list of strings?

Comment: I want to change values of some columns and write table again

Answer (score 3):

Use regex with `python` engine

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=r'\,|\t', engine='python')
```

Comment: Getting this error: `ValueError: Expected 86 fields in line 2, saw 93`

Comment: You data is not properly formatted then. No delimeter can catch it like you imagine it

Comment: If I specify comma as delimiter I get error `pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 83 fields in line 3, saw 85`, if I specify tab as delimiter I manage to read table but values are `NaN` and for regex you suggested `ValueError: Expected 86 fields in line 2, saw 93
`

Comment: Data was given so there is no much I can do unfortunately

Comment: How big is it? You can try loading in chunks where the error lies.